# Programmatically set view height and position to fraction of screen size

Tags: java, android, view, height, pixel

I'm trying to set the height of a view in my application to a fraction of the total height of the user's screen. However, I can never seem to get it to quite work. Other solutions I've looked at for getting the height of the screen in pixels give a good approximate position, but the view position and height seem to vary from screen to screen.

How do I go about this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: IMHO you cannot get this. You will have to get the window height as well as the view height and then calculate the percantage...

Comment: The view position and height will obviously vary from screen to screen. But they will be proportionate

Comment: Use

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Comment: That's what I've been doing; getting the height of the screen using "getDisplayMetrics" then setting layout parameters and y position of the view, but it doesn't seem to work how I'd expect. That is, the height and position of the view aren't quite what I want them to be and it varies from screen to screen despite these values each being an apparent fraction of total screen height.

Answer (score 0):

well i think you might already have tried this trick below.

get width and height in pixels by using displayMetrics.widthPixels and displayMetrics.heightPixels respectively

then (assuming you have relative layout, whose position you want to set) set params as-

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam;
```

set margin as below

```
//margin (left, top, right, bottom) in pixel CO-Ordinates
layoutParam.setMargins(screenWidth/108+screenWidth*seekTime/29, screenHeight/13, (screenWidth-screenWidth*seekTime/29)+screenWidth/108, (int) (screenHeight/0.9));
```

here the numbers in denominator (108, 29, 13, 0.9), i got from trial and error method, that suited my project best

so basic idea is to set it at a fraction of screen height in pixel.

for my project it worked for all the devices we tested on an also we had orientation locked to 'portrait'. might not work properly if screen orientation is changed

*Another way might be*, if you would like go after it...
Make margins a function of screen width.
eg:

```
if(height>4){
        set at half height
    }
else{
        set at one-third height
    }
```

(and i do hope that you do call display matrix only once in your whole app and store, say at launch of first activity, and just manipulate the margin from the stored place)

Comment: This is essentially what I've been doing, but in combination with using ".setY(number)" on my view. I want to avoid hard coding in numbers found through trial and error as this will result in the look of the app varying for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

to get the screen dimensions you can use:

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;

You will want your view to preserve its aspect ratio, when resizing it, regardless of the screen size.

If you have a view, when it looks ok is 400 px wide and 200 px high, you will want to preserve this ratio (400/200) = 2 after you rescale the layout.

Lets say the screen is 480 w x 800 h and you want your view to be 50% of the width of the screen.
Then 480 * 50% = 240 will be target width of your view.

But we want to preserve aspect ratio: 
400/200 = 2 = target width / target heigh = 240 / X
then X = 240*200/400 = 120

Your new Layout for the view should be 240w x 120 h (240 / 120 = 2 -aspect preserved-)

Here, as Android devices have different sizes in terms of aspect ratio (width / height), you may want to check how the new hight fits within the screen hight.

120 / 800 = 15% in this case.

If the hight % doesn't meet what you need, or if the hight happens to be out of bounds of the screen, or if the new hight doesn't meet a minimun height you want, then, you do the inverse calculation by setting a height and calculating the new width allways respecting the aspect ratio.

In this way the view won't deform on any screen.